# bin/bash script: toggle bluetooth state?

Tags: script, bash-scripting

I'm trying to do an alfred workflow that toggles my bluetooth connection.

```
STATUS=$(/usr/local/bin/blueutil status)

if [ $STATUS == "on" ]
then
/usr/local/bin/blueutil off
echo "off"
else
/usr/local/bin/blueutil on
echo "on"
fi
```

what am I doing wrong here?

It doesn't do anything.

Comment: What output does `/usr/local/bin/blueutil status` produce?

Comment: "on" – http://cl.ly/UGor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that `blueutil` writes to `STDERR` and not `STDOUT`.  In that case, merge the former into the latter while capturing the output of `blueutil`.

```
STATUS=$(/usr/local/bin/blueutil status 2>&1)
```

Moreover, you want to see whether the output *contains* `on`, so instead of:

```
if [ $STATUS == "on" ]
```

say:

```
if [[ $STATUS == *on ]]
```

instead in order to *match* the desired string.

Answer (score 0):

blueutil now works a bit differently, with the status returned as '1' or '0' rather than words. Here is a script that toggles the bluetooth state, may it help others who ended up on this page via google:

```
#!/bin/bash
STATE=$(/usr/local/bin/blueutil -p)
((STATE ^= 1))
/usr/local/bin/blueutil -p $STATE
```

The `^=` is the bitwise XOR-equal operator, which flips a variable between 0 and 1.